# Remove list of running apps from the lockscreen

Tags: lock-screens, privacy, android-14

When I pull down the notification shade *twice* when the phone is locked, I have [an entry](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-force-close-apps-from-the-notification-shade-in-android-13/) at the bottom of the shade showing "X apps are active". When I tap the entry, not only can I see a list of running apps without unlocking the phone, but I also have buttons to stop them.

How can I disable the list when the phone is locked?

---

From the [linked article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-force-close-apps-from-the-notification-shade-in-android-13/):

The button on the bottom of the shade:
[image: button showing "2 apps are active"]

The active apps list:
[image: A list of active apps with stop buttons]

Comment: I can only see the apps that have active notifications in that list on my lock screen. Have you restricted notifications on lock screen or do you allow them all?

Comment: Just in case it's relevant, could you mention the device model?

Comment: @Robert I have them restricted, but it's not about the notifications but about the list of active apps, as [described here](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-force-close-apps-from-the-notification-shade-in-android-13/). Did you pull down the shade twice?

Comment: @AndrewT. I think the list is present on *all* phones with Android 13 and 14.

Comment: Pulling down twice does not change anything because I start at the upper screen border, this way you directly get the full page: screenshot https://postimg.cc/xJs7YYn6 And the two active apps are just my "permanent" notifications because of VPN and battery monitor. Other active apps do not appear there. Tested with  a Samsung tablet on Android 14 and a Pixel phone on Android 13, both with a PIN protected lock screen.

Comment: I have a Samsung Galaxy M12 running on Android 13. While the "active apps in background" is shown on the Recents Screen, I don't see it on the lock screen or on the quick setting drawer. Granted, manufacturers do like customizing their Android... So, I'd assume your device is Pixel 6 or newer, as per the article?

Comment: @AndrewT. Pixel 8 and on my phone it looks exactly like in the linked article, butI can access it from the lockscreen, while the article claims one needs to unlock the phone first. Maybe that was changed in Android 14?